# How to draw string on an image to be assigned as the background to a control in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

The string length can change, height is the same. The font is large for visibility.

But how do I do this?

I know painting on the control directly. But how do I do this without creating an image file, but all in memory. Because the string image will change with user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like ...

```
Image i = new Bitmap(200, 50);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(i);
g.DrawString("Message", new Font("Arial", 8), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0,0));

pictureBox.Image = i;
g.Dispose();
```